# Python is detecting syntax error that's right

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm watching this YouTube tutorial on how to make a video game, and now we're converting it to exe, and this is my setup code to convert the game to exe (not the game's code itself):

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("pygame sentdex.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="A bit racey",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":["car.png"]}} #if you have other included files put them here. like fonts.
    executables = executables)
```

When I try convert, this happens:

```
    PS C:\Users\Damon Tattersfield\Desktop\video game\code\python codes> python setup.py build
  File "setup.py", line 9
    executables = executables)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\Damon Tattersfield\Desktop\video game\code\python codes>
```

It keeps saying the e in `executables` is wrong, even though it works fine for the YouTuber, and I've changed it to capital e, removed, retyped it, but it's saying it's a syntax error, when I'm 99% sure it's not.

This is the YouTuber's link by the way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdLkP8MrOXLe_rKuf6r80KO&v=EY6ZCPxqEtM

How do I fix?
thanks...

Comment: You might be missing a comma, in any case it probably has nothing to do with that poor “e”.

Comment: you seem to be missing a comma after the `options`.  i.e. `myfunc(a,b c)`, rather than `myfunc(a,b,c)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a comma after your second keyword argument:

```
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="A bit racey",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":["car.png"]}}, # <-- HERE
    executables = executables)
```

Often when you get a `SyntaxError` and the interpreter tells that the error is on for example line 9, the mistake is actually a missing comma, parentheses, or a quote on line 8.

Also, whenever you get an exception/error you are **never** "right". I can guarantee you that the interpreter won't mistakingly tell those.